# Why is a good-looking or sexually attractive person called a 'snack'?

Tags: etymology, slang

Why is a good-looking or sexually attractive person called a 'snack'?

Young people often use it this way, and it's a sense listed in some dictionaries.

> a sexually attractive person.
> *"it's clear from the pics that her new husband is a total snack"*
> [[Oxford Languages]](https://www.google.com/search?q=snack%20define)

([This funny video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBcLRqxqSuo) from Lily Singh (time 1:25) is where I first encountered the word used in that sense.)

Comment: Can you give an example of use?

Comment: I've never heard this usage in the US Midwest.

Comment: It's a metaphor, food ~ romance. See the more more obscure [What does it mean to call someone a 'drink of water'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235815/what-does-it-mean-to-call-someone-a-drink-of-water/) .

Comment: @DJClayworth I just added a video example

Comment: I hope it's not too inappropriate to mention it here, but oral sex is a thing. So the fact that sexual attractiveness invokes the image of eating with your mouth is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Do you have an example not by a comedian? Comedians often misuse phrases for comic effect.

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry I don't have any other prominent example ready other than what one might get out of a quick Google search

Comment: clmpare German *Schnuckel* "cuty", *Schnecke* "snatch"

Answer (score 4):

I've heard a bunch of taste-related words (*[scrumptious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrumptious)*, *[delicious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delicious)*, *[yummmy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/yummy)* etc.) used informally to describe someone who's attractive, so it seems that people often slangily associate foodstuffs with sex appeal.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/snacc/) has an entry for the slang word *snacc*, and in the etymology, they explain when the original term began to get repurposed:

> In the 2000s, snack emerges as slang for an attractive person (i.e., someone who looks sexy enough to scarf down like a snack). This sense of snack is recorded on Urban Dictionary and found on Twitter by 2009.

It's not too complicated as far as etymologies go. As an eloquent Redditer [put it](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/b46tut/comment/ej4k84v/), "*snacks are yummy. the person looks yummy."*

The same idea is expressed in a little more detail on *[slang.net](https://slang.net/meaning/snack)*:

> A snack is a person who looks attractive, almost tasty, which makes you want to eat [them] up, much like an actual snack.

Doesn't take a frog to make the leap between the two ideas.

Comment: Yes, +1, and if you want a noun also used in the same way, "dish" is fairly common. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dish): "an attractive or sexy person")

Comment: "Dish" has been a fairly common US term for an attractive female for at least 50 years.

Comment: Note also  ***snackbar (n.)***
(US campus) a girl- or boyfriend.

- 1996 [US] Eble Sl. and Sociability 70: A ‘girlfriend or boyfriend’ was a snackbar, and go for sushi meant ‘kiss passionately’.

Comment: .... Eye candy.

Comment: I wonder about that spelling, snacc. And this: "It’s also internet slang used when cute animals are seeking or enjoying a snack". How embarrassingly dumb. :)

Comment: It's essentially a *British* usage, but several decades ago Joan Bakewell was touted as [*the thinking man's **crumpet***.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thinking-woman-s-man-s-crumpet) But ***He's yummy, She's a dish, Hungry for love,...*** are so common I don't really see there was much of a question here in the first place.

Comment: @FF You made me laugh with that. From WP: _After the release of the 1997 film Titanic, Kate Winslet was dubbed by one newspaper as "the sinking man's crumpet"_. Also, _Bakewell herself dislikes the epithet_ (No surprise there!) I guess this Muir was referencing Christopher Hampton's "thinking man's television" quote (which must have been fairly popular), since it seems that it was only a few years after Hampton.

Comment: Yes:  lust, dehumanizing its object, thus often seeks to disguise itself as a fellow deadly sin, gluttony.

Comment: @Lambie - The spelling started as a Crip thing. https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/succ/