# Snatch block etymology

Tags: etymology, nautical-terms

Why is the word *snatch* used in the term *snatch block*?

> [snatch block](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snatch-block) — a fairlead having the form of a block that can be
> opened to receive the bight of a rope at any point along its length.
>
> [fairlead](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fairlead) — a pulley, thimble, etc., used to guide a rope forming part of the rigging of a ship, crane, etc., in such a way as to prevent chafing.
>
> [snatch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/snatch) — to seize by a sudden or hasty grasp.
>
> [block](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/block) — a solid mass of wood, stone, etc., usually with one or more flat or approximately flat faces.

A *snatch block* is used to make pulling or lifting something *easier, but* ***slower***. Whereas the word *snatch* means to grab something ***quickly***. So it seems counterintuitive to me that the word *snatch* is used in that context.

Related: [YouTube - Why Snatch Blocks are AWESOME (How Pulleys Work) - Smarter Every Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2w3NZzPwOM)

Comment: I would think it comes from the Miiddle English  verb **snacchen** which can mean *to sieze prey*. See the MED. I think it can refer to seizing with the fangs, as one of the attestations refers to a snapping dog. the related Old English words refer to something pointy.

Comment: Snatch block: 
(Nautical Terms) nautical a block that can be opened so that a rope can be inserted from the side, without threading it through from the end
[C17: *so called because the rope can be inserted quickly: figuratively, the block snatches it.* https://www.thefreedictionary.com/snatch+block

Comment: I think speed of hoisting is not the idea but the speed with which the block can be opened to take the bight and then be closed upon it.

Comment: Exactly right TimR. If a block doesn't open, the line has to be fed in from an end -- which might already by tied to something. A snatch block lets you grab the line in the middle.

Answer (score 10):

**Snatch** has been used in nautical contexts since Middle English. The verb emerged in the 13th century, meaning to "take a sudden snap" or to suddenly grab or catch something, in both literal and figurative ways (Oxford English Dictionary, "[Snatch, v.](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/snatch_v?tab=meaning_and_use#22144796)"). By the late 15th century, the verb-stem *snatch-* emerged in a nautical context ("[snatch-., comb. form](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/snatch_combform?tab=meaning_and_use#22146152)"):

> 1485–
> Nautical. Denoting devices capable of rapid attachment, or to which a rope can be quickly attached, as snatch-cheek, snatch-cleat, snatch-hook, †snatch-pulley, snatch-sheave (cf. snatch-block n.).
>
> > 1485 - "Snache poleis, ij." in M. Oppenheim, Naval Accounts & Inventories Henry VII (1896) 50
>
> > 1495 - "Snache poleyes with oon shever of brasse to ye same" in M. Oppenheim, Naval Accounts & Inventories Henry VII (1896) 192

**Snatch block** emerges in the early 17th century as a combined form of this nautical usage and **block**, meaning a block with a hole one can quickly run a rope through ("[snatch-block](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/snatch-block_n?tab=meaning_and_use#22146480)," n.):

> A block having a hole in one side to receive the bight of a rope.
>
> > a1625 - "Snatch block is a greate Block with the Sheever in it and a Notch cutt through one of the Cheeks of it by which Notch they reeve anie Roape into it." H. Mainwaring, Nomenclator Navalis (MS British Library Harley 2301)

So putting the clues together, what is *quick* about the snatch-block isn't the rope itself. Instead, the block is set up so that one can quickly run the rope through the hole (see "snatch-"). Alternatively, the block quickly *catches* or *snatches* the rope.

Comment: These blocks open so the middle of rope can be put over the block (pulley) part and then snapped closed. Otherwise, you have to start at the end, which is often impossible on a rigged sail.

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is likely wrong, following the most common interpretation of the question, *how can snatch block derive from [modern English] snatch?*

In reality, *snatch* has no good etymology. Nautical *snatch* should be treated as a possible witness of the verb's etymology, notwithstanding the dates of attestation (@Merlin) because a derived simplex is prima facie more likely to be used in writing.

*block* likely pertajns to the original sense of a stopper. It could be related to German *Blech* "sheet metal" as a band of sheet metal wound into shape, because **a* canonically goes to o (cp. *boat*) and has thus to be borrowed, cp. *bloke*.

*snatch* compares *Schnauze* – *snout* –  because the sn-initial cluster has no etymology, sobfar, other than *imitative* (cp. *snack, snot, snicker* etc.). The sense of firmly  holding (with teeth) is likely secondary.

The original sense will have been *nook, nut, noose*, as a loophole that doesn't chaf the rope too badly. That this was the ideal place for a clamp is coincidence.

*Snatch* "cunt" proves the original meaning, inasmuch as this sense is not at all expected to be found in classic writing until the device had lost any resemblance in form or function. German *Schnecke* ("concha") rather than *Schnauze* ("mouth") still attests to this. In the sense of "coil" (eg. snail shell) it is close enough to functional clamps, not unlike a carabiner.

See also: [Why is a good-looking or sexually attractive person called a 'snack'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610547/why-is-a-good-looking-or-sexually-attractive-person-called-a-snack) comparevSp. *esposa*